# XML query with xpath find one section with multiple attributes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Hi I want to find user information with room number and birthdate . I load xml file with file_get_contents and simplexml_load_string.I get the data successfully from url. Orginal URL XML data:

```
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="userinfo.xsd" generated="2013-03-22T11:16:13">
<userinfo>
<BirthDate>1967-12-27</BirthDate>
<RoomNo>111</IDNo>
<ClientName>AAA BBB CCC</ClientName>
</userinfo>
<userinfo>
<BirthDate>1970-01-01</BirthDate>
<RoomNo>121</IDNo>
<ClientName>DDD EEE FFF</ClientName>
</userinfo>
<userinfo>
```

I tried with this code : $found = $xml->xpath('//userinfo/BirthDate[contains(text(), "1967-12-27")] and RoomNo[contains(text(), "111")]')[0]; But I didnt get anything.

Comment: Can you please ensure error reporting is turned on, your XML is malformed (see RoomNo/IDNo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a go at cleaning up your code and produced a working sample

```
$string = '<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="userinfo.xsd" generated="2013-03-22T11:16:13">
  <userinfo>
    <BirthDate>1967-12-27</BirthDate>
    <RoomNo>111</RoomNo>
    <ClientName>AAA BBB CCC</ClientName>
  </userinfo>
  <userinfo>
    <BirthDate>1970-01-01</BirthDate>
    <RoomNo>121</RoomNo>
    <ClientName>DDD EEE FFF</ClientName>
  </userinfo>
</dataroot>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $string );
if( $user = $xml->xpath( '//userinfo[RoomNo="111" and BirthDate="1967-12-27"]' ) )
{
  var_dump( (string) $user[0]->ClientName );
  // string(11) "AAA BBB CCC"
}
```